# Are these frequent calls to a function that returns a fixed value in dblquad avoidable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

This script calculates the electric field at (x0, y0, z0) from a uniformly charged annulus using SciPy's [dblquad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html).

My question is about the use of `gfun` and `hfun` which define the functional dependence of the inner integral limits on the outer integral variable. This would be a cookie-cutter shape if I'd chosen to integrate in cartesian coordinates, but when I use cylindrical coordinates the functions return constant floats.

Is there a way to eliminate these function calls that simply return constants in order to avoid the time penalty of the function calls?

The example may not be optimized in other ways, but it's just a simple example to show the use of `gfun` and `hfun`.

```
def Excalc(r, th):
    x, y, z = r*np.cos(th), r*np.sin(th), 0.0
    return (x0-x) * ((x0-x)**2 + (y0-y)**2 + (z0-z)**2)**-1.5

def Eycalc(r, th):
    x, y, z = r*np.cos(th), r*np.sin(th), 0.0
    return (y0-y) * ((x0-x)**2 + (y0-y)**2 + (z0-z)**2)**-1.5

def Ezcalc(r, th):
    x, y, z = r*np.cos(th), r*np.sin(th), 0.0
    return (z0-z) * ((x0-x)**2 + (y0-y)**2 + (z0-z)**2)**-1.5

def gfun(x):
    return rmin

def hfun(x):
    return rmax

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import dblquad

twopi = 2.*np.pi

# annulus of uniform, unit charge density
rmin, rmax   = 0.8, 1.2
thmin, thmax = 0,   twopi

# point to evaluate the field
x0, y0, z0 = 1.5, 0, 1  

eps = 1E-10

Ex, Exerr  = dblquad(Excalc, thmin, thmax, gfun, hfun, epsrel=eps)
Ey, Eyerr  = dblquad(Eycalc, thmin, thmax, gfun, hfun, epsrel=eps)
Ez, Ezerr  = dblquad(Ezcalc, thmin, thmax, gfun, hfun, epsrel=eps)

print Ex, Ey, Ez
print Exerr, Eyerr, Ezerr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the definition of `dblquad`, the `gfun` and `hfun` parameters are of type `callable`, which means they will be called by `dblquad` in a function-call way.

However you can make the code a little bit neat by using Python's `lambda` instead of a normal function. Example:

```
Ex, Exerr = dblquad(Excalc, thmin, thmax, lambda: 0.8, lambda: 1.2, epsrel=eps)
```

Comment: I see, So there's no way to avoid it. I'm not so familliar with `lambda`, for some reason I can't wrap my head around it. Maybe it's finally time I learned. Thanks!

Comment: It's really easy to pick up, like: `Ex, Exerr  = dblquad(Excalc, thmin, thmax, lambda: 0.8, lambda: 1.2, epsrel=eps)`

Comment: Oh, for a constant it's very easy, I see. Thank you x2!

Comment: I've used your answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/190268/145009)  and linked to it in the script. Thanks again!